# Fanged chimera used for doorknocks and gargoyles?

Tags: celtic

Can you help me identify this fanged grotesque that I saw in the movie [The Wicker Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wicker_Man)?

I am guessing it is some sort of Celtic mythical element? I have also seen it used elsewhere as door knocks or gargoyle downspouts but can't remember where. Does it have its own name, like the *griffin* being a mythical beast with a lion's body and an eagles' head?

[image]

Comment: Closest I could find is called 'guardian motif':   https://www.1stdibs.com/furniture/asian-art-furniture/metalwork/large-brass-door-knockers-guardian-motif/id-f_9775421/